# 'work' or 'working'

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between:

> 1. ... algorithm which will be programmed in the later stage **work** with
>      use of high-level programming language, such as: C#, etc.
> 2. ... algorithm which will be programmed in the later stage **working**
>      with
>      use of high-level programming language, such as: C#, etc.

What is the right form?

Comment: Neither sounds very fluent to me

Comment: Neither form seems right. I'd use "...algorithm which will be programmed in at a later stage with the use of a high-level programming language such a C#."

Comment: or ".. algorithm which will be implemented in a later stage using a high-level programming language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option seems better of the two. However it is also a bit wrong as well. That's because with "algorithm" (singular noun) a plural verb goes ("works"). If it was "algorithms", "work" would have been alright.

The 2nd statement seems to make no sense, at least the part given. If there was anything before ( as indicated by the dots), it may make sense.

Comment: `Works` isn't a plural verb. It is the third-person singular form of the verb `to work`. "Plural" doesn't mean "has an `-s` on the end."